# Domain parsing using list of tlds

Tags: php, regex

I am using following regex to parse domain...

```
$pattern = "/(\w+)\.(co.uk|uk|com|edu|gov)/";

preg_match($pattern, "something.abc.co.uk", $matches);
```

How can i use a text file/string of tlds at place of `co.uk|uk|com|edu|gov` so this regex can be used to validate multiple tlds.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: By reading it from a text file to the variable and using it the same way

Comment: I want to replace this `(co.uk|uk|com|edu|gov)` with multiple tlds,so maybe it could match text file as string for matches for TLDs.  I can't figure out, how to achieve the same.

Comment: Maybe `implode('|', $list);`? The `.` in `co.uk` should also be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean there should be a txt file listing all valid domains? If so, you could try it this way:

```
// valid_domains.txt

 co.uk|uk|com|edu|gov

// PHP file

/* Modified code starts */

$myfile          =  fopen("valid_domains.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$valid_domains  =   fread($myfile,filesize("valid_domains.txt"));
fclose($myfile);

/*Modified code ends*/

$pattern        = "/(\w+)\.(".$valid_domains.")/";    // Modify this line
$result = preg_match($pattern, "something.abc.co.uk", $matches);

var_dump($result);       // int(1)
```

Comment: This is a dirty trick, i have thought about it before but thing is i want to match tld in text file which has not proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This will read in a file where each tld is on it's own line, clean them up and generate a pattern.

```
<?php
//read in the list of tlds
$list = file('listOfTLDs.txt');

//clean up list
array_walk($list, function(&$val){
    // remove leading/trailing whitespace/newlines
    $val = trim($val);
    // escape preg special characters
    $val = preg_quote($val, '/');
});

//make pipe separated list
$list = implode('|', $list);

//make the pattern
$pattern = "/(\w+)\.({$list})/";
```

Comment: This is a dirty trick, i have thought about it before but thing is i want to match tld in text file which has not proper formatting.